# Simple Design of friends list database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small issue with making a friendship system database.
now I have a table called friends
let's say:

table friends:

```
    you      friend      approve     since
_________________________________________________
   wetube    youtube     1           4-12-2012
   facebook  wetube      1           4-12-2012
```

and i have this query code to fetch the friends of user called wetube.

```
mysql_query("SELECT f.* FROM friends f inner join users u on u.username =
f.you WHERE f.friend = 'wetube' UNION ALL SELECT f.* FROM friends f inner join users u on
u.username = f.friend WHERE f.you = 'wetube'");
```

now what I want exactly is how to fetch the friens of wetube and show it to him on his page.

fixed:

Finally I fixed the problem.
so this is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `friends` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `you` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `friend` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `since` date NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

and this is the php code to fetch the user friends

```
<?php
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$friends_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (friend = '$username' OR you = '$username') ");
while($friends_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($friends_sql)){
if ($username == $friends_row['you']) {
echo $friends_row['friend']."<br/>";
} elseif($username == $friends_row['friend']) {
echo $friends_row['you']."<br/>";
}
}
?>
```

try it yourself it works 100%

Answer (score 4):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend='wetube'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $row['friend'], ' - ', $row['since'];
```

Comment: @Mustafa M Jalal: $result = mysql_query("select * from friends where friend='wetube' AND you='facebook'");

Comment: that won't work too. think about it more. i want facebook is friend with wetube and wetube is friend of facebook
so if facebook load his page he sees wetube his friend also the same with wetube he sees facebook his friend

Comment: How are you planning to bring your friends to the page? Link or Login?

Comment: bring friends of wetube on his page
and also bring friends of facebook on his page

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question, but a completely normalised database would have two tables for this system.

Since this is a many-to-many relationship, I would do something like this:

```
UsersTable
------------------
id: int, serial
name: varchar
email: varchar
...
```

And

```
RelationshipTable
------------------
id: int, serial
user1_id: int, foreign key on UsersTable.id
user2_id: int, foreign key on UsersTable.id
approved: boolean
since: date
```

With a properly designed and normalised database, it will be *much more* easy to manage and create your queries.

Comment: guys please i have no problem with query i only have problem with mysql_fetch_assoc how will i show the record??? which field should I use

Answer (score 1):

You mean just the rows that have wetube in the [friend] column?  You might just be over-thinking the joins:

```
SELECT * FROM [friends] WHERE [friend] = 'wetube'
```

If you want where wetube is in either column:

```
SELECT * FROM [friends] WHERE [friend] = 'wetube' OR [you] = 'wetube'
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM [friends] WHERE [friend] = 'wetube'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [friends] WHERE [you] = 'wetube'
```

Comment: then how will I show records do i show you records or friend record on page?

Answer (score 1):

All of the wetube's friends are:

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (friend = 'wetube' OR you = 'wetube') AND approve = 1
```

I would suggest removing the column approve and instead keeping a table of requests. This will mean that all approved requests are in the friends table and all pending approvals are in the friend_request (or whatever) table.

This two table design is more efficient because you do not always have to check that approve = 1 when you want to show friends (which is probably pretty often).

Comment: you just got it right but how will i show the record
let's say i'm at wetubes page what column should i show the [you] or the [friend]?? i have no idea about this

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.
You want:
CASE WHEN friend = 'wetube' THEN you ELSE friend END

Comment: yes kind of like that but i guess there is another way to do that

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not understanding this exactly.

Select * from Friends f 
where f.you = 'wetube' or f.friend = 'wetube'

Guess your looking for user info as well, reason for inner joins.

Maybe removing the approval column, and have 2 records. The 2nd record is when the friend approves as a friend.
Then you can easily see who YOU are friends with, and they in return are friends with.

```
wetube --> youtube
facebook --> youtube
youtube --> wetube  wetube would approve a friendship request for youtube, adding a record
wetube --> facebook
```

Then you could  much easily ask who is friends of wetube.
Just an idea, probably not the answer you were looking for.